# How to select only name of a specific column in pandas

Tags: python

`Employee        Role           Working hrs`

`John       Senior accountant   40`

`Mark       CFO                 38`

`Mete       Developer           35`

Objective is to return header of column 2: Role

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is named 'df', and these are the only three columns, the following will return the column header 'Role'

```
df.columns.values[1]
```